# How write Bengali "AA"?

Tags: keyboard

I've added Bengali Keyboard in Ubuntu 12.04. Every button in the keyboard has 2 character. Pressing `shift` + any button, writes the upper character in the button. But I'm unable to write the following character shown in the picture.

[image: Cant Write this character]

Can anyone please help me showing which key combination is required to write this character?

Comment: Looking at that layout: the bottom has a "Level 3..."  that is probably the one ;) (level 1 is normal, level 2 with shift, level 3 is what you are looking for). Probably ;)

Comment: yes brother. But how can I write this "Level 3" keys? @Rinzwind

Comment: Many many thanks Brother @ Rinzwind. I did not knew the name of this key "Level 3". I searched and found this "level 3" in keyboard (Right to space bar). Now I can write this "AA" character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your image to mark the keys:

[image]

You need to hold the "Level 3 super" key and then press the AA key (similar to holding shift).

---

And to make it complete: you can choose what key to use in the "options" of keyboard layouts:

[image]